# How to get data from Form 1 ListView and then present each data from Form 2 MessageBox?

Tags: c#

I'm building a mini application that contains a listview on Form 1, I would like to get all ListView data from Form 1 and then present each columns data from Form 2 messagebox. But I try many times before that the result show the last columns data only. So how can I improve the code as below?

```
In Form 1:

Form2 newform = new Form2();
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwItemList.Items)
            {
                newform.Getdata = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            }

In Form 2:

private string getitem;

public string Getdata{
get{
return getitem;
}
set{
getitem = value;
}
}
...
MessageBox.Show(getitem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `form2` add this `property`:

```
public ListViewItemCollection ListViewItems { set; get; }
```

Then when you open `form2` in `form1`:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.ListViewItems = lvwItemList.Items;
```

Then in `form2` you can use `ListViewItems` anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.